# Unable to install or use pipreqs to create requirements.txt file for dependencies

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I have a Python project that I would like to send to someone else. I am trying to create a `requirements.txt` file containing the required dependencies for this script so that my partner can run the script.

I tried installing `pipreqs` like this: `pip install pipreqs`.
This outputs the following:

```
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
Requirement already satisfied: pipreqs in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (0.4.11)
Requirement already satisfied: yarg in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from pipreqs) (0.1.9)
Requirement already satisfied: docopt in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from pipreqs) (0.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\nroll97\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from yarg->pipreqs) (2.26.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\nroll97\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from requests->yarg->pipreqs) (1.26.8)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\users\nroll97\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from requests->yarg->pipreqs) (3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\nroll97\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from requests->yarg->pipreqs) (2021.10.8)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer~=2.0.0 in c:\users\nroll97\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from requests->yarg->pipreqs) (2.0.11)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.4; however, version 22.0.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Python310\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I then tried to create the `requirements.txt` file by running the command:

```
pipreqs ./my_calc.py
```

from the folder that contains the Python script and I get the following error:

```
bash: pipreqs: command not found
```

Why can't I use `pipreqs`? I use `pip install` all the time for other libraries.

Also, I am on a Windows computer. Is there an easier way to create the `requirements.txt` file even if its manually?

These are the only imports:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import openpyxl
import os.path
import math
from tkinter import filedialog
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still wasn't able to get the `pipreqs` to work so I just made the `requirements.txt` file manually by first finding out which versions of the Python modules are being used.

I found that out like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import openpyxl
import os.path
import math
from tkinter import filedialog
# VERSIONS OF LIBRARIES AS OF DEVELOPMENT - 04/28/2022
print("Version of pd: " + str(pd.__version__)) # 1.4.2
print("Version of openpyxl: " + str(openpyxl.__version__)) # 3.0.9
print("Version of tkinter: " + str(tkinter.TkVersion)) # 8.6
```

And then created the `requirements.txt` from those values like this (but only for the imports that are not already included in the standard Python library):

```
pandas==1.4.2
openpyxl==3.0.9
```